# read <td> and then load popup when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a table row completely clickable by embedding a hidden `<td>` containing a link like so:

```
<tr class="simplehighlight junk" >
  <td>07/09/2011</td>
  <td>Jennifer Woods Memorial GP</td>
  <td>A52</td>
  <td>Harris, Fred</td>
  <td>1900</td>
  <td>Nikolayev, Igor</td>
  <td>2395</td>
  <td class="text-center">0-1</td>
  <td style='display:none;visibility:hidden;\'> games/game1242.php </td>
</tr>
```

I was using colorbox to target the table cell like so:

```
<!--colorbox-->
<script src="./js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('tr.junk').colorbox(
    {
      iframe:true,
      transition:'elastic',
      speed:'100',
      width:1030,
      height:550,
      href: function(){
        return $(this).find('td').eq(8).text();
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```

But I am want to use jquery:

```
<!--Another Pop-up for games table-->
<script src="./js/jquery.popupWindow-min.js" ></script> 
<script>
  $('.diagram-popup').popupWindow({centerBrowser:1, height:560, width:1024});
</script>
```

How can I add the class `diagram-popup` to the 8th table data cell and have the row, when clicked, read the contents of that cell?

Answer (score 1):

```
<td class='diagram-popup' style='display:none;visibility:hidden;\'> games/game1242.php </td>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.diagram-popup').click(function(){
      $(this).html(); //contents of cell
   });
});
```

Is that what you're looking for?

**Update:** Ah, I see...you're wanting to click any cell in the row and then go get the contents..  Maybe this will help...

```
<td style='display:none;visibility:hidden;\'> games/game1242.php </td>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('table tr td').click(function(){
      var cell = $(this).parent().find('td:last');
      cell.addClass('diagram-popup'); //Not clear on if this is what you're wanting, you can always just print out the diagram-popup class server side 
      cell.html(); //contents of cell
   });
});
```

I haven't tested that, but it should work.

Comment: It didn't work. Maybe someone could check the source of http://communitychessclub.com/games-nu.php

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a class to your clickable row, I would probably change the `tr` in question to read something like this:

```
<tr class="simplehighlight junk diagram-popup" data-href="games/game1242.php" >
```

And I would completely drop your hidden `<td>`, it's unecessary.

And the jquery:

```
<script src="./js/jquery.popupWindow-min.js" ></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
    $('.diagram-popup').click(function(e){
      $(this).popupWindow({
        windowURL: $(this).data('href'),
        centerBrowser: 1,
        height: 560,
        width: 1024
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm sorta not a fan of having windows pop out when I click stuff…I don't think it presents a good user experience.  But to each their own.

Here's a jsfiddle as proof of concept:  http://jsfiddle.net/UujmJ/1/

Comment: DW ... and destroys DataTables. This is original with DataTables functioning: http://communitychessclub.com/games-save.php and the new version based on your suggestion (which I very much appreciate for the effort) is here: http://communitychessclub.com/games-nu.php

Comment: Hmm in your source I see two calls to popupWindow, one mine, and one an old one that doesn't have a url.  Probably should only be using the one?  If my answer worked for you, you should accept it as the right one too :)

Comment: I just commented out the other popupWindow and it still DW. I am almost ready to adopt your suggestion of abandoning the "row-click" idea and adding a simple <td> to load the gamescore.

Comment: Hmm well without seeing the code that you tried using I can't tell what you're doing wrong and it looks like you already changed it sorry!  :)